# Will returning a nil value from a block passed to Rails.cache.fetch clear it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's suppose I have a method like this:

```
  def foo
    Rails.cache.fetch("cache_key", :expires_in => 60.minutes) do
      return_something
    end
  end
```

`return_something` sometimes returns a `nil` value. When this happens, I don't want the `nil` value to be cached for 60 minutes. Instead, the next time I call `foo`, I want the block passed to `fetch` to be executed again.

Is `Rails.cache.fetch` working like this by default? Or do I have to implement this functionality?

## Update (with Answer)

Turns out, the answer was no, at least when using Memcached.

Comment: do Rails cache empty array too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends on the implementation of the cache-store that you are using. i would say that it should not cache `nil` values, but empty strings are ok to cache.

look at the [dalli store implementation](https://github.com/mperham/dalli/blob/master/lib/active_support/cache/dalli_store.rb#L84-L113) ie:

```
  def fetch(name, options=nil)
    options ||= {}
    name = expanded_key name

    if block_given?
      unless options[:force]
        entry = instrument(:read, name, options) do |payload|
          payload[:super_operation] = :fetch if payload
          read_entry(name, options)
        end
      end

      if !entry.nil?
        instrument(:fetch_hit, name, options) { |payload| }
        entry
      else
        result = instrument(:generate, name, options) do |payload|
          yield
        end
        write(name, result, options)
        result
      end
    else
      read(name, options)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Currently dali_store accept a options[:cache_nils],  which can cache nil
 https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli/blob/master/lib/active_support/cache/dalli_store.rb#L84-L113

Comment: Rails support `skip_nils` now https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25437

Answer (score 3):

The updated answer to this question is: By default `fetch` caches `nil` values, but using the `dalli_store` engine you can avoid it with `cache_nils` option:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("cache_key", expires_in: 60.minutes, cache_nils: false) do
  return_something
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting, the defaults for Dalli have changed in recent years - the flag for nil-caching is currently false by default. See  https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli

It's definitely worth adding a test to check that your setup does what you expect (especially for production mode)